# Как в библиотеке файлов wordpress создать папку?

Tags: wordpress, файлы, библиотеки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как в библиотеке файлов wordpress создать папку? А то все файлы сгружаются в одну кучу, что сильно неудобно

Comment: Никак, если средствами самого WordPress. Можно поискать плагины, но то, что я видел, все кривое.

Comment: По умолчанию физически файлы разносятся по месяцам. Логически можно отфильтровать по месяцам и типам. Для большей гибкости  фильтрации в этом интерфейсе  необязательно их разносить физически - достаточно логически. Для этого есть плагины. Для физического, кстати, тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь  [Custom Upload Dir](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) плагином для подобной задачи.

[Тут пример фильтров для кастомизации](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/#screenshots)